# Find elements from a list in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I come today with a rather simple problem. I have a dataframe containing values for individuals.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['John', 'Edward', 'Sean'],
                 'Age': ['21', '44', '35']})
```

What I am looking forward to do is to remove some lines that contain individuals from a list.

```
list = ['Edward', 'Martin', 'Paul']
```

So the desired output should be a dataframe without Edward's line.

I have tried some things but I only get a list with False and True Values :

```
print(df.index.isin(list))
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just use these booleans on your df like `df[bools]`

Comment: basically you want `df.loc[~df['Names'].isin(list)]`, presumably you haven't really named a variable as `list` which would shadow the type `list`

Comment: You should never use 'list' as a variable name, since it is an important keyword. Use 'mylist' etc.